# How to fix the error with the "greatest per n group" query in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having specific problem with SQL query in phpMyAdmin. My query works good only for the first created entity in my table(and for it's childs) but doesn't work for another entities. What can be the problem?

I've tried to use the query in different databases and it works properly.

```sql
select title_media,MAX(LENGTH(text_media)) as TEXTFieldSize
                    from media
                    where LENGTH(text_media) = 
                    (select MAX(LENGTH(text_media)) from media ) AND fk_event=id_event
```

I expect the output to be media title that has the longest text_media field. For the first entity it works good, but for the following I get only empty rows.

Comment: Your subquery `(select MAX(LENGTH(text_media)) from media )` will **always** fetch the same result

Comment: Would you give us table structure along with sample datas, so we can do tests and help you giving a proper answer ?

Comment: What is `fk_event` and `id_event`. Is `id_event` some kind of constant? You are trying to find longest `text_media` in that specific `fk_event`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find media event with longest `test_media` for specific `fk_event` (that is equal to `<id_event>`) then you are missing the condition in the subquery

```
select m1.title_media,
       MAX(LENGTH(m1.text_media)) as TEXTFieldSize
from media m1
where LENGTH(m1.text_media) = (
   select MAX(LENGTH(m2.text_media)) 
   from media m2
   where m1.fk_event=m2.fk_event
) AND m1.fk_event=<id_event>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. As you said, problem was in the subquery condition.